# Date picker with openly visible list of horizontal months dial and date dial

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is it possible to have a date picker like an openly visible list of horizontal months dial and date dial (one line of months and below it one line of date) where the user can horizontally scroll through it and the combination which is made in the centre that will be the selected date?

[image: Screenshot]

After scrolling and making combinations to jump on any date the user will be able to see entries of that day.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You just have to develop it...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Holger Just](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just)  mentioned, you'll need to code it.

Or another path would be to use an already built package from pub.dev and customize it to fit your needs.
The one which looks quite similar to your needs is: [calendar_timeline_sbk](https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_timeline_sbk)